# How to theme extra pages: Diazo Theming vs Portal View Customizations

Tags: plone

Our institute has Plone 5.0 and 4.3 running and are migrating dozens of older plone sites into them.

We have created a Diazo theme and it is hosted to provide our theme out to all plone sites. There are specific plone pages like the Login that must be changed. There are two ways we see to do this:

1. Portal View Customizations.  Problem is we can't host this template centrally and can't change it one place to change it everywhere.  This will bring maintenance issues.
2. Diazo.  We could put all the html in the index.html and then drop code we do not need through the rules.xml.  However this feels super hacky and inelegant.  The index file will grow and grow in size.

What is the best approach to something like this?

My idea: (Please tell me if this good or bad)
In Diazo, the rules.xml would load a subset rules file called login-rules.xml.  In the login-rules.xml, I'd put a replace rule.  The replace rule would have within it all the login HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You've really got two kinds of problems here.

One is deciding where to intervene for your login pages. The other is how to manage deployment of custom code.

If the changes you need are strictly ones of presentation, Diazo is a reasonable place to handle it. Remember that you may use different theme documents, with your rule set making an early decision of which theme (html) file it uses under what circumstances.

If the changes you need are beyond simple presentation and require custom logic, or if the presentation changes start to require complex custom XSLT, make the changes via view customization. But do not do that with the Portal View Customization tool. Customizations that are needed on multiple sites should go into Python packages maintained in a source-control repository like git. That goes for Diazo rules and theme files as well as templates.

You may create the skeletons for these packages with ZopeSkel or mr.bob. Use the JBOT method within these packages to customize individual template files.

Managing deployment is much easier when you're using file-system packages from a repository. You may use mr.developer within your buildout to automatically check out the current version (or a particular tag or branch) of a package when you run buildout. Then, when you need to push changes to multiple servers, you run buildout on each one and restart the ZEO clients. That may be automated with tools like Ansible. See Plone's Ansible Playbook for examples.

I've used several bits of Plone-specific jargon in the above. All of these are well-documented at http://docs.plone.org.